# The UIButton does not always fire

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have seen several similar questions but not anyone that has the answer to this question.

I have a view with some programmatically created buttons. The problem is that the buttons only fires sometimes. If I touch a button at *exactly the same spot* several consecutive times it will either *always fire* or *never fire!* (I use the simulator and the MacBook's track-pad to hit exactly the same spot). I have the feeling that only 50% of the pixels within the button are active!!

Here is how the button is created:

```
// Button Memory Recall
UIButton *buttMR = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buttMR.frame = CGRectMake(55, y, 50, 40);
[buttMR setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttMR addTarget:self action:@selector(memoryRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttMR addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownButt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
buttMR.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
buttMR.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
buttMR.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[buttMR sizeToFit]; // remove this later...
[self addSubview:buttMR];    
self.buttMRec = buttMR;
```

The app is rather complex. The view that contains the buttons (view B) is a subview of view A. The button view is not always shown. It is created, and slides in to cover view A when it is needed.

[image]

Update:
For some very strange reason, the info button on view A seems to cause the problem. If I replace that button by a rounded rect button, it seems to works fine.

Comment: memoryRecord: is not firing ah? . Have you set view userinteraction.enabled = NO ?

Comment: can you also post the code for memoryRecord: and touchDownButt: which of the functions is not firing?

Comment: userinteraction.enabled = YES, the two functions contain NSLog-messages. Both functions are sometimes not working (but sometimes they do).

Comment: I just tried your code and works fine 100%, you need to give more clues

Comment: @AntonioMG The app is rather complex but I have added a short description. What is peculiar is that some pixels on the button seem to work.

Comment: Try to temporarily increase the button size and perform some testing to see if the problem persists. I have had the same kind of issues when using smaller sized buttons in the past.

Comment: @sangony Thanks but it does not work. I have found that the buttons works if I enlarge view-A and place view-B on top of an empty spot. I guess, therefore, that the problem is the buttons on view A.